# Rails + Foundation with only grid and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, zurb-foundation

I'd like to use foundation in my Rails3 app but only the forms and grid.

When I add `@import "foundation";` it all works..

But when I use `@import "foundation/forms";` it crashes with the following message:

```
Undefined variable: "$formSpacing".
```

Seems like some settings are missing..

Anybody here that has experience with this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$formSpacing is a foundation global.

You have to import foundation globals before you import forms.

Put this before your form import.

```
@import "foundation/globals";
```